# iOS resign IPA from appstore with developer profile

Tags: ios, certificate

I am trying to resign iOS app which I downloaded from appstore with my own certificate how to do it I am stuck in that . I am using OS X Yosemite  This is what I did

```
#  ResignApp.sh
#  
#
#  Created by Naveen P on 3/11/15.
#
IPA="/RnD/Dropbox\ 3.7.ipa "
PROVISION="/RnD/iOSTeam_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision"
CERTIFICATE="iPhone Developer: ABCD " # must be in keychain
# unzip the ipa
unzip -q "$IPA"
# remove the signature
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature Payload/*.app/CodeResources
# replace the provision
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
# sign with the new certificate (--resource-rules has been deprecated OS X Yosemite (10.10), it can safely be removed)
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --resource-rules Payload/*.app/ResourceRules.plist Payload/*.app
# zip it back up
zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload
```

but it terminates without resigning showing this

```
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
Payload/*.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: its for some testing purpose is it possible ?

Comment: Have you got any success? Can you please share me your complete bash script. I am interested to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the --resource-rules parameter from the arguments list. You can use codesign without that parameter, given that you aren't using another parameter that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

as information you provided,**"--resource-rules"** has been deprecated; 
so,

1. check version of your system;
2. remove the --resource-rules parameter

i can resign the ipa this way; but it can't run normally, it flashback. 
till now i have no idea about it;